# C++ character ASCII value to string

Tags: c++

Very basic question.  I am having problems in converting a `char` to a `char*` that points to the actual character. Googling yielded information on strcpy, string, sprintf, etc. After many, many attempts at trying to understand the problem, I still can't get it to work.

I have a character array `recv_msg` which contains the ASCII values of the characters I need. I need to store the characters (not the values) in a vector `msg`.

What I have:

```
std::vector<char> msg;
char recv_msg[max_buffer_length];
...
int i;
for (i=0;i<bytes_transferred;i++) {
    msg.push_back(recv_msg[i]);
}
// Problem: when I process my msg I see 49 instead of '1'.
```

If I do the following as a sanity check, I do get the behavior I need.  That is, I see a '5' and not a 53 (ASCII code for 5).

```
std::vector<char*> msg;
...
int i;
char *val;
for (i=0;i<bytes_transferred;i++) {
    msg.push_back(val);
}
// No problem: when I process my msg I see '5' instead of 53.
```

So I need to turn the ASCII code values (`char`) into their character representation (`char *`).  How on earth do I do this?

I want to solve the problem at this stage, and not have to do the ASCII -> character conversion when processing the message.

Comment: Use `std::string` or would that be too easy?

Comment: Of course you are going to see a 53, a char is just a 1 byte number. Can you clarify how are you "processing" your data? Printing?

Comment: @MrLister The std::string seemed a bit wasteful, so I wanted to understand what was going on.

Comment: @LarryPel It was a bit of a convoluted explanation since this is part of an NPAPI plugin...  Somehow user P0W recognized my problem (from my poor explanation), and recommended something that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your

*"I need to store the characters (not the values) in a vector msg"*

Try following, btw ASCII `53` is `'5'` only, may be your `recv_msg` stores ascii value only.

```
std::vector<char> msg;
char recv_msg[max_buffer_length];
...
int i;
for (i=0;i<bytes_transferred;i++) {
    msg.push_back(recv_msg[i] - '0'); //Subtract 48 from numerals, 
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly what I needed.  I now understand what my problem was.

Answer (score 2):

A `char` is just a number, so if you're seeing it as `53` instead of `'5'` it's because that's how you're displaying it.

You could change to store the incoming messages as strings, e.g.:

```
std::vector<std::string> msg;
char recv_msg[max_buffer_length];
...
int i;
for (i=0;i<bytes_transferred;i++) {
    msg.push_back(std::string(&recv_msg[i], 1));
}
```

But this seems inefficient if all you really have is single characters. An alternative would be to convert to a string when you "do something" with the character, e.g.:

```
std::string str(&msg.back(), 1);
```

Or even:

```
char str[2];
str2[0] = msg.back();
str2[1] = '\0';
```

Comment: Yup, I tried the string approach at some point but it seemed wasteful as you point out.  I understand I could change the way I display the number.  My problem was how to store the characters inside the vector in a similar way than the string literal "5" gets stored.  P0W's method of `msg.push_back(recv_msg[i] - '0')` achieved this.  Thanks for the detailed explanation though!

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `char` and `char *` has absolutely nothing to do with the representation of a character, and its numeric representation.

With ASCII:

`printf("%c\n", '5');`

gives you `5`, and:

`printf("%d\n", '5');`

gives you `53`. It's always going to be *stored* as `53`, turning it into a printable `5` character is just a question of how you elect to output it - you can't "store the characters (not the values)", because the value always is what you store. Even when you write `'5'` in your source code, your compiler just turns it into `53`, i.e.:

```
if ( '5' == 53 ) {
    puts("This will always print.");
}
```